# Problema al copiar código en otro documento

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, xampp

Mi pregunta se divide en dos partes: (1)una duda tonta que no consigo resolver por más que busco y (2)llevada a un problema(que creo que se deriva de la duda) más serio que no consigo resolver.

La duda que no consigo resolver es, porqué copiando el código del archivo manualmente(Cntr C - Cntr V) de un archivo php(el cual funciona perfectamente), alojado en un servidor, a otro archivo .php vacío, este último no "funciona". Sin embargo, si copio el propio archivo(no el código fuente, sino el fichero) en el mismo directorio funciona perfectamente.

Ahí está mi duda, ahora esto me ha derivado en un problema:

He montado mi servidor local(xampp) en otro PC, todo igual, me COPIO la carpeta donde tengo mis archivos php que me interesan, de los que he hablado. Repito, todo exactamente igual, rutas relativas en los documentos y todo perfecto. Y sin embargo el archivo php que funciona perfectamente en mi otro PC no funciona en este nuevo.

La consola del navegador me da fallo en la línea donde comienza el código php en el archivo. ¿No reconoce código php por haberlo copiado? Llevo buscando posibles causas por todas partes y no consigo nada... alguna idea?

EDIT:

Información adicional: El código de mi archivo php se compone la mayor parte por javascript con jquery, el código php está dentro que una etiqueta script, no creo que tenga que ver realmente con el problema, pero nunca se sabe.

Comment: ¿qué significa "a pelo"?

Comment: Abro el archivo en notepad++  -> seleccionar todo -> Cntr C -> Cntr V en el nuevo archivo(Notepad++)

Comment: supongo que te refieres a manualmente? o con programas externos?

Comment: @Alan manualmente todo

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con '_no "funciona"_'?¿Cómo _no "funciona"?¿Podrías compartir el código del fichero que tratas de copiar y falla (al menos la parte con PHP)?¿Qué extensión tiene el fichero?¿Cómo abres la parte de PHP?¿Dónde colocas el fichero .php en tu servidor? Es prácticamente imposible saber qué está fallando con un fichero cuyo contenido desconocemos

Comment: @RodrigoPérezLópez claro, a lo que nos referimos es que aclares eso en tu pregunta ya que "a pelo" es un regionalismo una forma de hablar de donde tu provienes, ten en cuenta que no toda la comunidad va a entender que quisiste decir. Abrazo.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Me explico, los dos ficheros tienen extensión .php, llamemos el fichero original cal.php y al copiado cal2.php. cal.php me abre un calendario cargado con jquery mediante una librería e interactúa con mi servidor local perfectamente, mientras que cal2.php no me carga el calendario, sí el html. Los archivos los abro accediendo a localhost (_localhost/calendario/cal.php_). Los dos ficheros los tengo en mi carpeta htdocs de mi servidor, dentro de otra carpeta(calendario) junto con todos los archivos necesarios.

Comment: @Alan lo entiendo, debí explicarme mejor ^^. Lo he aclarado en la pregunta.

Comment: Podría ser un problema de permisos o codificación, ¿podrías confirmar si los dos ficheros tienen los mismos permisos?¿y la misma codificación de caracteres (charset)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Los permisos igual, pero efectivamente era un problema de codificación. He usado un plugin del Notepad++ para comparar ambos ficheros y me marcaba líneas con acentos y eñes. También tenía el fichero copiado(cal2.php) con codificación ANSI y lo he pasado a UTF-8. Y funciona perfectamente ahora... muchas gracias a todos, al final las cosas terminan teniendo sentido.

Comment: Genial, me alegro que te haya funcionado. Ahora, lo que no sé es que se debería hacer con la pregunta. Por una parte podrías poner una respuesta con lo que hiciste para solucionar el problema y cambiar la codificación de los ficheros (**como respuesta y no como edición a la pregunta**); pero por otra, el problema en sí no está directamente relacionado con la programación por lo que queda un poco fuera de los [temas pertinentes a SOes](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hecho! Muchas gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 3):

Problema solucionado, el problema estaba en la codificación del archivo copiado a código. Al crear un archivo vacío, la codificación por defecto es ANSI, por lo que los carácteres con tildes o de otras regiones(ñ) no los reconocía. Algunos de esos carácteres estaban en nombres de variables y funciones en el código javascript, no los reconocía y la carga de javascript fallaba. Supongo que ahí estaba todo el problema.

El problema se soluciona tan sólo cambiando la codificación del archivo a UTF-8, con el notepad++ por ejemplo es bastante sencillo: *Codificación -> Codificar en UTF-8*

Comment: Gracias por moverla a una respuesta. Cuando pase el tiempo mínimo, márcala como aceptada